# How can I create user tables for java like aspnet_regsql in asp.net?

Tags: java, jsp

How can I create user tables for java like aspnet_regsql in asp.net?

Comment: Java devs aren't going to know what `aspnet_regsql` is. Explain what you're talking about.

Comment: I usually use in .net aspnet_regsql for creating users and roles tables. According to java, what do you do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is Tomcat Realms

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html

scroll down to JDBC.

if you are using another application server, they will have a similar configuration